# Retrieving Images from Firebase in portrait Orientation using Picasso in an ImageView

Tags: android, image, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

I have successfully made an App which uploads pictures to firebase from the phone's Album in a portrait orientation using `Picasso`, but when i try to retrieve some of the pictures , they come when they have changed the orientation, maybe when the image size is bigger. Below is the sample pic.

[image]

I use also `Picasso` while retrieving the image from `Firebase` , How can i  be able to make an automatic detection when the image is not portrait to be set portrait without loosing an image quality like **Facebook**.

Below is the code which selects an image from the Gallery.

```
imageSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


             imageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.with(c).load(imageUri).fit().into(imageSelect);
            //imageSelect.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
```

This is the code which Retrieves an image from Firebase to the RecyclerView

```
  public void setImage(final Context c,final String imageUrl){

   //

        Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).fit().centerInside().rotate(90).placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imagePost, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

                //Reloading an image again ...
                Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
                        .into(imagePost);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace it

```
Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).fit().centerInside().rotate(90).placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
```

On this

```
Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).fit().centerInside().placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
```

here too much `rotate(90)`

Comment: Hello @ ANDRO thanks for the reply , but  when i remove `rotate(90)`, those images come well but others change  which were in the portrait , Now the problem here is when i select an image from the Album into the imageView it displays well in an a portrait way , but when i upload it to Firebase and i Retreive it back , some images change their orientation and others stay in a portrait way. Isnt there i way i can auto check the images which may change their orientation  with `Picasso` help

Comment: Firebase image in a normal orientation?

Comment: yeah exactly, but it seems when the image is big , it comes when the orientation is changed , if i may ask , is there  a way i can resize all the images in one size without loosing quality , i think that might slove the problem

Comment: Strange. But Picasso library itself can not change the orientation. Perhaps the problem is in your code or in Firebase

Answer (score 1):

try check if the orientation of image changed before upload to Firebase and after retrieve it.