# Image Orientation changes While Uploading an Image from gallery to Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

Am having an Android App when i upload an image Which has approximately  559.23KB and above Firebase storage changes its orientation. Below is the sample picture.
[image]

And this is how it appears in my android App.

[image]

Is there any way i can make `Firebase Storage` , not to change the orientation of an image greater than 559.23kB.

Is there `Firebase Storage` Rules for this solution , or theres a Java code ?,

This is my Upload Image Code

```
imageSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });

private void startPosting() {
        mProgress.setMessage("Uploading Image...");


        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && imageUri != null) {
            mProgress.show();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("BlogImages").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                    Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    DatabaseReference c = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("EventTitle").setValue(title_val);
                    newPost.child("EventDescription").setValue(desc_val);
                    newPost.child("EventImage").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                    newPost.child("PostId").setValue(c);



                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));


                }
            }


            );


        }
```

The `onClickListener`, on the button which Uploads.

```
postButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });
```

This is how i attach an image from the gallery , then i upload it to Firebase Storage. After clicking.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


             imageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.with(c).load(imageUri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageSelect);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your image upload code to firebase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Images from Firebase in portrait Orientation using Picasso in an ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336873/retrieving-images-from-firebase-in-portrait-orientation-using-picasso-in-an-imag)